# Using Google Spreadsheet API without composer : how to make it work?

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api, google-api-php-client, autoload

I'm having an issue for 3 days using Google Spreadsheet API on my FTP server.
OVH serv does not permit to install of Composer so I am trying to get it without this tool.
I tried several things but so far, none of them work properly :

- Install the **[v1-master](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master)** branch
- Add it into my vendor folder with my **/vendor/autoload.php** which looks like this:

```
    function google_api_php_client_autoload($className){
  $classPath = explode('_', $className);
  if ($classPath[0] != 'Google') {
    return;
  }
  // Drop 'Google', and maximum class file path depth in this project is 3.
  $classPath = array_slice($classPath, 1, 2);
  $filePath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . implode('/', $classPath) . '.php';
  if (file_exists($filePath)) {
    require_once($filePath);
  }
}
spl_autoload_register('google_api_php_client_autoload');
?>
```

- And tried invokes Google API in my script.php like this :

```
<?php

define('DOCROOT', dirname(__FILE__));

use Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
use Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory;

if(!function_exists('classAutoLoader')){
    function classAutoLoader($class_name) {
        $class_name = str_replace('\\','/',$class_name);
        require_once(DOCROOT."/src/".$class_name.".php");
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('classAutoLoader');
```

- or also like this :

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

- I'm trying to make these API calls with **Google Spreadsheet API**

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Sheets API PHP');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
    $spreadsheetId = "1LLpSUVBAA3dSiyOG4lKDHDxqeldazzdads";
```

- I've also added **json files** (***composer.json, composer.lock, and credentials.json***) that I was using with Composer (on local, it was working well) at my ROOT folder.
- Other than that I have tried to make it work with other google libraries such as **googleapis-master** and **google-api-php-client-2.8.1**

Content of file token.json:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "ambient-airlock-*****",
  "private_key_id": "*****************",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIE*****************==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "*****************@ambient-airlock-*****************.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "*****************",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/*****************%40ambient-airlock-***********.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

I am sure I am missing something in the way I'm using these but I will be grateful if someone could explain to me how to make it works properly without Composer, please.

Comment: What is your error ? Was it working 3 days ago? Have you taken a look into [this guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php)?

Comment: No error showcased but the script does not execute the google API part. It should add rows from MySQL on a spreadsheet. 
I've tested it in a localhost environment and it is working with Composer installed and a local mysql but it is not working when I put it on my FTP server. 
I am able to connect to the DB and to showcase the result on a HTML page, but it does not add the rows to the spreadsheet.
Yes I've been already through the guideline create API key, email setup, spreadsheet id  and etc

Comment: Do you have the [generated](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php#step_3_set_up_the_sample) ```token.json``` file? If you could share your complete authorization code *with no sensitive data* I could check if you are missing something with regards to [oAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing)

Comment: Yes I've generated one and selected admin rights through Google API console, and added it to the root file of my project. I've updated the code of the token.json in my question.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve with Sheets API? Create a Spreadsheet? Edit it?

Comment: I would like to add rows on an existing spreadsheet, and when launching the script, automatically add the rows from my db to the spreadsheet. I use PDO to connect, then make a query and pass it to the Spreadsheet API

Comment: Could you please share the part of your sample code (with no sensitive data) where you add these rows to your Spreadsheet with the use of Sheets API to look if there are any errors on it? Thanks ! :D